# go2go.playground - expected type, found 'type' (and 1 more errors)

Tags: go, generics, go-playground

I try to run examples from the [design draft](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-contracts.md) ([The Next Step for Generics](https://blog.golang.org/generics-next-step)) on
<kbd>[go2go.playground](https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/prh6TR-92-w)</kbd>

```
type Pair(type T) struct { f1, f2 T }
```

, but get an error

```
prog.go2:14:11: expected type, found 'type' (and 1 more errors)
```

Where can I find actual `go generics` `design draft`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to test offered `generic` realization, and compare it to other language realization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's old syntax since a few weeks ago.  Try

```
type Pair[T any] struct { f1, f2 T }
```

Note that square brackets are now used instead of round brackets and the `type` keyword is no longer used.  You also must use the `any` constraint, whereas previously you could leave the constraint out if there was no restriction on the type parameter.

BTW Conventionally `Pair` refers to a struct with 2 different types for the 2 fields like `type Pair[T1, T2 any] struct { first T1; second T2 }`

See [go2go Playground](https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/AyqmjI7kp6z) for example code that builds.

As mentioned in the first paragraph of the 2019 design draft the new draft is https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md

Answer (score 6):

You're looking at outdated design draft.

This one is current: https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md

So, it's not:

```golang
type Pair(type T) struct { f1, f2 T }
```

But:

```golang
type Pair[T any] struct { f1, f2 T }
```

Comment: not worked for me, `expected ']', found any`

Comment: @mohammad try using the latest go2go.  There were versions (early - mid 2020) that allowed square brackets but support for `any` had not yet been added.

Comment: Both these approaches maintain the same error

Comment: @joash I checked it on go2 playground, it seems to be working: https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/ch1b-dzi-Fj

Comment: A bit more extensive example: https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/aRSD4rih-Qs

Comment: It seems it  is my golint that does not recognise the generic types then